# Voltar para o Menu Inicial quando apertar ESC com JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Como posso fazer minha aplicação voltar para o menu inicial após apertar `ESC`. Atualmente consigo usar KeyEvent apenas quando algum componente está associado, como um `TextField`, `Button`, etc.. Quero apenas apertar o Esc sem nenhum componente estar selecionado e a aplicação retornar para o menu principal. Exemplo de como faço (Associando um componente):

```
txtPesquisar.setOnKeyPressed(k -> {
            final KeyCombination ENTER = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER);
            if (ENTER.match(k)) {
                atualizar();
            }
        });
```

Comment: O que é o seu menu principal? Você tem várias telas?

Comment: Sim, tenho várias telas. Meu menu principal é apenas uma tela de "boas vindas"

Comment: Ok, mas você já sabe mudar as telas, né? Seria só o caso de fazer isso através de uma tecla de "atalho"?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Quando eu apertar uma tecla muda de Cena. A Scene é instanciada no meu método Main dessa forma: `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmLogin.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);`

Comment: Depois pego a `scene` e jogo em uma variável estática. E com essa variável eu manipulo todas as transições de cenas do sistema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar um handler na tua scene.

```
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent t) -> {
    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
        //codigo para ir ao menu inicial
    }
});
```